# How to use subprocces library to open new Powerpoint file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, subprocess, powerpoint

Even though I searched everywhere I couldn't find an appropriate answer for how to use subprocess library to open a new Powerpoint file.
I've looked for the office .exe file names which said it's `powerpnt.exe`
I tried but this and `powerpoint.exe` in subprocess.call: `subprocess.call(["powerpnt.exe"])`
But it's not working.I also tried `subprocess.Popen("start powerpnt.exe", shell=True)` and `subprocess.run()`
.Of course, I also tried another options of subprocess,which all failed.

I can use Subprocess to open Microsoft Word by the commend `subprocess.call(["write.exe])` (not word.exe).
I **am** able to open existing word file with Subprocess using the following code:
`subprocess.run(["write.exe",app_name])` But I found nothing that works about opening a exisitng\new PP with subprocess. someone can help?

Also, is there any documentation about the .exe files\the suffix of the micorosft files when using subprocess?

My overall code is quiet simple:

```
import errno
import os
import subprocess

def m_open(path):
    try:
       subprocess.run(["POWERPNT.exe",path]) # call the powerpoint\the file
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
            print("So this app doesn't exist...") # handle file not found error.
        else:
            raise #Something else went wrong while trying to run the program\file

if __ name__ == "__ main__":
    m_open('C://def/work.pptx')
```

Comment: in your code `app_name` is not defined

Comment: Your parameter 'path' is unused, instead you use 'app_name' in your subprocess call. Is this a typo?

Comment: Oh.for the sake of the ask I changed it. In my code (which is similar in all the way but that) there is no typo.